# How to load a keystore from a bytearray in python

Tags: python, jce

In java l use this:

```
public static KeyStore loadFromByteArray(byte[] keyStoreData, String password) {
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_KEYSTORE_TYPE);
        keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(keyStoreData), password.toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return keyStore;
}
```

any idea how to do the same thing in python?

Comment: Maybe look at https://pypi.org/project/pyjks/

Comment: l did but l can only find how to load it it from a file

Comment: You can load from a file like `store = jks.KeyStore.load(KS_PATH + "/jks/RSA1024.jks", "12345678")` or from bytes like `store = jks.KeyStore.loads(store_bytes + b"\x00"*1000, "12345678")`

Comment: I had a look at the source code and the `load` method, is just a wrapper which will open a file name read its as bytes and then call the `loads` method using the bytes. https://github.com/kurtbrose/pyjks/blob/174b38b5c2bb03701808bb39324dfe52a462a4fa/jks/util.py#L82